# SBT. Вызвать main метод с аргументами в таске

Tags: scala, sbt

Есть таска

```
lazy val myCustomTask = TaskKey[Unit]("description of my task")
myCustomTask := {
    val arg = "arg1"   // Пока нигде не используется.
    (runMain in Compile).toTask(" com.company.Main").value
}
```

Которая отлично работает.
Но мне необходимо передать аргумент, и если я его добавляю:

```
(runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $arg").value
```

то все падает с ошибкой

> error: Illegal dynamic reference: arg
>   (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $arg").value
>   ^
>   [error] Type error in expression

Как правильно передать аргумент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение через динамическую таску:

```
lazy val myCustomTask = taskKey[Unit]("description of my task")
myCustomTask := Def.taskDyn {
    val arg = "arg1"

    Def.task {
        (runMain in Compile).toTask(s" com.company.Main $arg").value
    }
}.value
```

Теперь аргумент в методе прекрасно читается